# Custom ASP.NET TextBox Control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I will try to be concise...

I need a custom ASP.NET TextBox that will take the user input and search a lookup table for a description and a corresponding code (i.e. "Retail Order" & "ABC"). The TextBox will display the description and store the code.

Scenario:
User types "ret" into the TextBox. AJAX is used server-side to find "Retail Order" and "ABC". Javascript changes TextBox to "Retail Order".

The AJAX side of things is working great. I even have a popup appear so the user can select from a list if more than one option is available.

My problem is...

What's the BEST way to store the code ("ABC") with the control during the AJAX request so that the server can retrieve it during a full post-back?

Storing the code in the ViewState doesn't work, because the ViewState doesn't change during an AJAX call.

I tried rendering a HiddenField alongside the TextBox; but that seems klugey.

Comment: A `HiddenField` is *not* klugey.  That is why they exist.

Comment: A hidden field is probably the way I would go. This way every control you instantiate has it's own containable way to manage it's data. Query string is out of the question. Saving session state is messy with n number of controls.  With a hidden field in the control, the data belongs to the control and is managed by the control, not by the page.

Comment: I do not know how to properly add a HiddenField to the form control collection within the confines of a custom TextBox. If I attempt to render the HiddenField in the TextBox's render override, the client ID isn't properly munged.

Comment: If it is possible I would update the view state after ajax call is complete. You can get the updated viewstate as a part of ajax call response.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, please point me in the right direction on how to do that. My custom TextBox control implements the `ICallbackEventHandler` interface.